# Why $\mathbb Z(\sqrt2)$ is not a lattice?

Tags: integer-lattices, lattices-in-lie-groups

The set $\mathbb Z(\sqrt2) = \{a + b\sqrt2 : a, b \in \mathbb Z\}$ is not a lattice, according to the book of Robeldo =

> because when you replace
> $a, b \in \mathbb Z$ by $a, b \in  \mathbb R$ we do not obtain all of $C$
>
> but only a $1$-dimensional real space (in this case just $\mathbb R$).
>
> In other words, there are no two points $w_1, w_2$ in $\mathbb Z$ whose coordinates are linearly independent in $R^2$.

This is hard to get for me.

How can I know that if I replace $a, b \in \mathbb Z$ by $a, b \in  \mathbb R$ we do not obtain all of $C$?

Comment: This is because $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: $C = {\mathbb C}$?

Comment: Note that your ${\mathbb Z}(\sqrt2)$ is more commony called ${\mathbb Z}[\sqrt 2]$.

Comment: @Magdiragdag yes you are correct in both comments

Answer (score 0):

Because $\sqrt{2} \in {\mathbb R}$, ${\mathbb R}[\sqrt 2] = \{ a + b \sqrt2 \mid a, b \in {\mathbb R}\}$ is equal to $\mathbb R$ and not to $\mathbb C$.

(I'm not sure what is exactly meant by "In other words, there are no two points $w_1, w_2$ in $\mathbb Z$ whose coordinates are linearly independent in $R^2$.")